# multivariate interval estimation

Tags: probability, statistics, estimation

I have several samples of probabilistic vectors, i.e, each sample is of the form $(x_1, \cdots, x_n)$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i\leq 1$ (they are sub-probabilistic vectors), how can I obtain a meaningful interval estimation on the "real" (sub-)probabilistic vector?

I assume this is a standard exercise of multivariate interval estimation, but my statistics is very basic, anybody helps me? Thanks.

Comment: Are these 'several' samples from the same distribution and to be used together in the estimation? Are the $x_i$ assumed to be proportions of counts in various categories? Is the reason the don't add to unity that there are some categories that are known to be exist, but observed (or observable)? Is this a theoretical exercise, or do you really have data so you can give some examples? As it stands, this question seems hopelessly vague to me. Context is lacking.

Comment: Many thanks for the comments. This is largely a theoretical question, but hopefully can be applied.  Samples are from the same distribution (but here each sample is a distribution which is irrelevant to the distribution underlying samples; it is a bit confusing). For the rest, yes, x is basically empirically counting, and some category is unobserved.